# separate column into different columns

Tags: r, dplyr

Some sample data:

```r
df <- data.frame(xyz1_t1 = sample(1:5, size = 100, replace = TRUE), 
                 xyz1_t2 = sample(1:5, size = 100, replace = TRUE), 
                 xyz1_t3 = sample(1:5, size = 100, replace = TRUE),
                 xyz2_t1 = sample(1:5, size = 100, replace = TRUE), 
                 xyz2_t2 = sample(1:5, size = 100, replace = TRUE), 
                 xyz2_t3 = sample(1:5, size = 100, replace = TRUE),
                 ab1_t1 = sample(1:5, size = 100, replace = TRUE), 
                 ab1_t2 = sample(1:5, size = 100, replace = TRUE), 
                 ab1_t3 = sample(1:5, size = 100, replace = TRUE) 
)
```

```r
> df %>% pivot_longer(cols = starts_with(c("xyz", "abc")))
# A tibble: 900 × 2
   name    value
   <chr>   <int>
 1 xyz1_t1     2
 2 xyz1_t2     4
 3 xyz1_t3     4
 4 xyz2_t1     2
 5 xyz2_t2     3
 6 xyz2_t3     3
 7 ab1_t1     2
 8 ab1_t2     2
 9 ab1_t3     5
```

How can I split the variable `name` into three variables `scale` (xyz, ab, ...), `item` (1, 2, ...) and `time` (1, 2, 3)?

Thanks for help!

Comment: The `dplyr` verb `separate()` does this.  I suggest checking the documentation for that function.  Alternative approaches would include `str_split()`.

Comment: I know, but I don't know which "by" parameter I can use in order to separate the first characters from the rest of the string starting with a number (e.g.  "ab1_t1" => "ab" and "1_t1" [I cannot split by position as the number of characters differs])

Comment: Ah, I see. If you provide the code you have used so far it lets people know where you are up to and provide more tailored help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using `tidyverse` already you could use `extract` from `tidyr`

```
df |> tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = starts_with(c("xyz", "ab"))) |>
      tidyr::extract(name, 
               into=c("scale", "item", "time"), 
               regex="([a-z]+)([0-9]+)_t([0-9]+)",
               convert=TRUE,
               remove=FALSE)

# A tibble: 900 × 5
   name    scale  item  time value
   <chr>   <chr> <int> <int> <int>
 1 xyz1_t1 xyz       1     1     1
 2 xyz1_t2 xyz       1     2     3
 3 xyz1_t3 xyz       1     3     3
 4 xyz2_t1 xyz       2     1     3
 5 xyz2_t2 xyz       2     2     2
 6 xyz2_t3 xyz       2     3     3
 7 ab1_t1  ab        1     1     2
 8 ab1_t2  ab        1     2     1
 9 ab1_t3  ab        1     3     1
10 xyz1_t1 xyz       1     1     1
```

Comment: For anyone who comes across this (very good) answer, the regex `([a-z]+)([0-9]+)_t([0-9]+)` equates to "a capture group with 1 or more letters, then a second capture a group with one or more numbers, then an underscore and a 't', then a third capture group with one or more numbers".

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```r
library(stringr)
df2 <- df %>% pivot_longer(cols = starts_with(c("xyz", "ab"))) %>% 
mutate(scale=str_extract_all(name,'^\\w[a-zA-Z]*(?=\\d\\_)'),
 item=str_extract_all(name,'(?<=\\w[a-zA-Z]{1,3})\\d*(?=\\_)'),
time=str_extract_all(name,'(?<=\\_\\w)\\d*'))
```